How is date mapping done via Jackson in a Spring Boot app
In spring boot rest controller how is a Date field mapped. Let us say we send in json {"receivedDate":"2024-05-15","num1":5}. How will it be mapped to a field in Java object having a property private Date receivedDate; (assuming java.util.Date)
we can consider, a simple class
public class SampleClass {
        Integer num1;
        Date receivedDate;
        //getters and setters
    }

and a Rest Controller in Spring Boot app,
public ResponseEntity getDetails(@RequestBody SampleClass sampleClass) {
     try {
        System.out.println("Execution of getDetails started. received date is: "+sampleClass.getReceivedDate());
...............}
....
}

I get result in my console as(I executed this api at 10:20 Am IST):
Execution of getDetails started. received date is: Thu May 16 05:30:00 IST 2024


So, the result contains 05:30:00 and not my present time. What if I wanted it to be just 00:00:00.0 instead of 05:30:00.0.
I am confused because in some stackoverflow answers, I came to know that Jackson's default behaviour is to do as per UTC. But it is doing as per IST though I have no configuration done.

It is always better work with UTC time, since for example in Frontend side based on their local date can be changed/updated. It is considered as best practices in an Enterprise Software Development World.

If you can, try a timestamp (Long), which is much smaller, and is great for both network transmission and database storage.

Hi @JonathanJOhx, I also want to proceed with UTC but it is taking by default for me IST. I have created a very simple spring boot 3 app, and getting time like that. though I wanted it to be UTC.

For context, this is a follow-up question to how is Time formatting done in a Java 8 vs 17 app.

Jackson converts correctly, the root problem is that you use an outdated, legacy class, known for the issues it's causing.
This has been asked countless times in different forms. Do not use java.util.Date, it is not actually a date, it is an instant since the epoch, the class is broken, misleading, causes many programmer errors, the API is deprecated for a reason.
In addition, toString(), which you use implicitly when printing, silently applies the default timezone when formatting the output, adding to the confusion. Your format is actually a simple date, without a time component, use java.time.LocalDate instead, part of java.time, the modern java date-time API, available since java 8.
@Data
public class SampleClass {
  
  private Integer num1;
  private LocalDate receivedDate;
}

If you need to conform to another API, which requires java.util.Date, there are convenient methods to make the conversion correctly.
Instant instantStartOfDay = sampleClass.getReceivedDate()
  .atStartOfDay()
  .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
Date asDate = Date.from(instantStartOfDay);


Hello, I need to set the date in a further api as in entityManager.createQuery(sql, Object[].class)
..setParameter("endDate", wrapper.getReceivedDate(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
This accepts a Date and not LocalDate. Could you please help with any convenient method

@AlokKumar you should still keep the suggested LocalDate for as long as possible and then convert it once you need it for your query

@AlokKumar There is an example at the end of the answer. But keep in mind that modern drivers support conversion from java.time classes to database date-time types.

@AlokKumar Are you using Hibernate? Which version? And which brand of database and which data type in the database? Without context I can’t evaluate your claim that you need an old-fashioned Date, but I am skeptical: this should work with all modern types from java.time.

There is no need to convert to java.util.Date. Hibernate already supports java.time classes, and you should be passing these directly to Hibernate instead of converting to java.util.Date. Just stop using java.util.Date entirely. @AlokKumar

You want to receive only the year, month, and day, and the default value of hours, minutes, and seconds is 00:00:00. You can use @JsonFormat annotations:
public class SampleClass {
    Integer num1;
    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd",timezone="GMT+8")
    Date receivedDate;
}

This will set the default time in your output to 00:00:00
Execution of getDetails started. received date is: Wed May 15 00:00:00 CST 2024


This will make the date completely and totally wrong. At best it will make the formatting appear correct in your timezone on your local machine.
